# Slack-API NodeJS bot response_url not working

Tags: node.js, slack-api

I'm currently developing my own slack bot using NodeJS.

For now not a complicated bot, you just type a command and you have an answer. That works fine.

Now I want to send an answer later, because my program call an external API.
As I read here in the [slack-API documentation](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands) at the end with title "**Delayed responses and multiple responses**" I need to do a post request to an url I received named "**response_url**"

Here is what I send in my post resquest :

```
{
   "response_type": "in_channel",
   "text": "My delayed text"
}
```

But when I do my post request with this content on url, nothing append...

Here is the intersting part of my code :

```
// modules
var http = require('http');
var https = require('http');
var url = require('url');

// Listen slack post request on /
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    var token = req.body.token;
    var team_id = req.body.team_id;
    var team_domain = req.body.team_domain;
    var channel_id = req.body.channel_id;
    var channel_name = req.body.channel_name;
    var user_id = req.body.user_id;
    var user_name = req.body.user_name;
    var command = req.body.command;
    var text = req.body.text;
    var response_url = req.body.response_url;

    if (isTokenValid(token)) {
        var subcommands = text.trim().split(/\s+/);

            // Check if sub-command is provided                                                                                                                                                    
            if (subcommands.length == 0 || text == '') {
                res.status(200).send('Usage: ' + USAGE);
            }else { // check sub-command                                                                                                                                                           
                switch(subcommands[0]) {
                    case 'test':
                    res.status(200).send(sendTest(response_url));
                    default:
                    res.end('Command "' + subcommands[0] + '" does not exists.\nUsage: ' + USAGE);
                }
            }
        // Bad token                                                                                                                                                                               
    }else {
        console.log('Bad token: ' + token);
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.status(403).send('Bad token. This is a personal slack plugin owned by Ninjava team');
    }
});

function sendTest(response_url) {
    var options = {
        host: 'my_api.com',
        port: '80',
        path: '/v2/content',
        method: 'GET'
    };

    getReq(options, function(output) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(output);

        var myresult = obj.result;

        var host = url.parse(response_url).hostname;
        var path = url.parse(response_url).pathname;
        var data = {
            "response_type": "in_channel",
            "text" : "This is the delayed message !"
        };

        postReq(host, path, data, true, function(output) {
            console.log(output);
        });
    });
    return "This is a direct message. Waiting for the delayed message...";
}

function getReq(options, callback) {
    //making the http get call                                                                                                                                                                
    var getReq = http.request(options, function(res) {
        var output = '';
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            output += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            process.stdout.write('\r');
            callback(output);
        });
    });

    //end the request                                                                                                                                                                          
    getReq.end();
    getReq.on('error', function(err){
        console.log("Error: ", err);
    });
}

function postReq(host, path, data, ssl, callback) {
    var post_data = JSON.stringify(data);
    var post_options = {
        host: host,
        port: '80',
        path: path,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(post_data)
        }
    };

    var protocol = ssl ? https : http;
    var post_req = protocol.request(post_options, function(res, b, c)     {
        var output = '';
        res.setEncoding( 'utf8' );
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            output += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            callback(output);
        });
    });

    post_req.on('error', function(err){
        console.log("Error: ", err);
    });

    // post the data                                                                                                                                                                           
    post_req.write(post_data);
    post_req.end();
}
```

I's done a lot of test.

1. I used https://requestb.in/q9zahiq9?inspect to test what my bot return with the post method (replacing the slack response_url by my requestb.in url). Everything seems to be ok
2. I used [PostMan](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) to check if my post request was recognized by the slack-API, just doing a post request on the response_url with the json object I provided at the begin of my post, and I success received the message on my slack channel.

I don't know why slack do not recognize my request and how to debug it...

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**
I solved it, please see my answer bellow

Comment: No one have an idea ? maybe is there a special thing to do with slack api when using post request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is intersted, I fixed my issue !

I just changed my request method :

```
function sendDataToSlack(response_url, data, callback) {
    request({
        url: response_url,
        method: "POST",
        json: true,
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)

        }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            callback(body);
        }
        else {
            console.log("error: " + error)
            console.log("response.statusCode: " + response.statusCode)
            console.log("response.statusText: " + response.statusText)
        }
    });
}
```

And it works fine

Comment: I wasn't able to get the above code to work, but I modified it slightly to  `request({
   url: response_url,
   json: data,
}) ...`

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you taking a look on the code of [nodejslack](https://github.com/marcogbarcellos/nodejslack), which I builthad some similar problems with GET requests so I used POST requests in some requests that should be GET. Sounds like a bug on the slack api, but i noticed it just happens when we send a GET request with JSON bodies, if you request a GET without any data(for example GET the list of all Emojis) you won't have this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I fixed it few weeks ago. I post an answer for who  were interested.